# How to get mathjax to display double digit or negative power to values?

Tags: support, mathjax

$x^-3$

$x^15$

$x^1^5$

This sucks. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use {...} to input more than 1 character.

$3^{15}$ will be given by 3^{15}

Answer (score 7):

L.Dutch already told you to use curly braces (`{}`) around the number. So you'd write `x^{15}` to get $x^{15}$.

**This applies more generally as well.** For example, `\sqrt xy` will render as $$\sqrt xy$$ but `\sqrt{xy}` renders as $$\sqrt{xy}$$ and correspondingly `\sqrt \sin xy` gives you $$\sqrt \sin xy$$ which is probably not what you meant, while `\sqrt{\sin{xy}}` becomes $$\sqrt{\sin{xy}}$$

As a general rule, any time you need to group multiple symbols in LaTeX (which Mathjax uses), those symbols need to be surrounded by `{}`.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, what did happen to my third example? $x^1^5$ I like the box, but how did I create it?

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight It's probably related to the *"Double exponent: use braces to clarify"* I see in the edit preview. Which is basically just telling you to do it the way you've now been shown. :-)

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight You can create a box by surrounding an expression with `\boxed{}`: e.g. $\boxed{x^{15}}$.